# Firefox extension to add my own 1-10 star ratings to YouTube videos (and where I can then also easily retrieve/find videos by my ratings)

Tags: firefox, youtube

1. Add my own 1-10 star ratings (instead of the current default of just "Like" and "Dislike") or, more generally, add my own n-star rating system
2. Easily retrieve/find videos by my ratings

"[YouTube Star Rating](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-star-rating/)" by Žan Ožbot seems to try to do something like what I want but unfortunately I just tried it and it doesn't work at all (installed it and don't see any difference at all to my YouTube pages).

Answer (score 1):

You can use tags in Firefox without an extension to rate all websites and classify them in categories. You click on the star at the right of the address bar and add your tags (comma separated).

1. Add your own n-star rating system. I've chosen from 01* to 10*. The asterisk at the end is useful to restrict the search to your specific tag (it will exclude bookmarks containing 10).
2. Use the search bar in the Library to find your videos or the main search bar (example : 10* science youtube).

With this system you also have the ability to backup your bookmarks, your ratings and other tags. You can find by name and sort by Most Recent Visit, Visit Count and Added.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion but for me this is too inconvenient to bother with